# how to conconate URL and string in react

Tags: reactjs, api, search, get, axios

I have a state:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            client: "10XXXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXX",
            uniq_id: " ",
            data: [],
        }
    }
```

Then, I want to display a detailed report based on the uniq_id entered in a form, so when the report number has been inputted and the user clicks the 'Search' button, the detailed report data will appear in the table provided under the search form. However, I have a problem to CONCONATE URL and UNIQ_ID state in the constructor above, this is a function to GET data from the API using AXIOS:

```js
notiket() {
        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: {'http://1111.111.0000/bla/?m=api&f=blablabla&client_id=bablablabla&uniq_id=${uniq_id}'},
        })
            .then((v) => {
                console.log(v.data)
            })
            .catch((e) => console.log(e.response))
    }
```

Comment: What you want is a template literal. Basically use backticks instead of quotes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @Jayce444 I don't understand, can you give me an example?

Comment: `url: { \`http://1111.111.0000/bla/?m=api&f=blablabla&client_id=bablablabla&uniq_id=${this.state.uniq_id}\`}`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use template strings? Then I think you are having a wrong syntax

Why are you wrapping url in an object?

Try this:

```
notiket() {
        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: `http://1111.111.0000/bla/?m=api&f=blablabla&client_id=bablablabla&uniq_id=${uniq_id}`,
        })
            .then((v) => {
                console.log(v.data)
            })
            .catch((e) => console.log(e.response))
    }
```

Otherwise you can always do:

```
notiket() {
        axios.get(`http://1111.111.0000/bla/?m=api&f=blablabla&client_id=bablablabla&uniq_id=${uniq_id}`)
            .then((v) => {
                console.log(v.data)
            })
            .catch((e) => console.log(e.response))
    }
```

Comment: the code above doesn't work, when I run it and input the report number, it comes out as below:                                                                                                                               
data: false, success: true, status: 200}
data: false
status: 200
success: true

Comment: If it runs as `success: true, status: 200`, that means that your request succeed. that is the matter of the endpoint result

Comment: I mean, the data doesn't appear on the console